# Return items in a list that occur with a given minimum frequency

Tags: python, function, sequence, probability

need help creating the function freqitems(S,p) that returns a sorted list of the items in sequence S that occur with at least p percent frequency, with no duplicates. example output should be like this:

```
>>> freqitems([2,2,2,3],50)
[2]
>>> freqitems(5*["alpha"]+["beta"]+3*["gamma"]+7*["delta"], 25)
['alpha', 'delta']
>>> freqitems(5*["alpha"]+["beta"]+3*["gamma"]+7*["delta"], 33)
['delta']
```

Comment: what have you tried?  this smells distinctly of copy/paste homework looking for an answer with little to no work...

Comment: on a side note its pretty trivial with the Counter module ...

Answer (score 1):

```
yourlist = 5*["alpha"]+["beta"]+3*["gamma"]+7*["delta"]

def freqitems(sequence, p):
  import collections
  counter = collections.Counter(sequence)
  return sorted([k for k,v in counter.iteritems() if 100.*v/len(sequence) >= p])

print freqitems(yourlist, 25)
print freqitems(yourlist, 33)
```

Comment: this is the type of question where its probably better for the future of programmers to logically walk them through each step rather than provide a complete solution...